# Converting string unicode to latin

Tags: python, unicode, latin1, python-unicode

I have the following result from some http requests:

```
 Tratamento\ da\ rejei\u00E7\u00E3o\ no\ cancelamento\ da\ desagrega\u00E7\u00E3o
```

i did some research and i was able to find this line of code, wich can convert utf-16 with the following line of code :

```
print unicode(u"\u00e3".encode("latin-1"), "latin-1")
```

My problem is, how i can convert a hole sentence of results from utf-16 to latin-1 ? Being more especific, how can convert or replace it to:
    "Tratamento da rejeição no cancelamento da desagragação"

Comment: That's `unicode` not `utf-16`

Comment: @jamylak I took the reference from http://www.charbase.com/00e7-unicode-latin-small-letter-c-with-cedilla

Comment: that site also says unicode and doesn't mention utf-16, you are using unicode escapes

Comment: Both strings you've posted are the same (apart from the strange `\ ` escape). No conversion needed.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the whole string.

```
>>> u'Tratamento\ da\ rejei\u00E7\u00E3o\ no\ cancelamento\ da\ desagrega\u00E7\u00E3o'.encode('latin-1')
'Tratamento\\ da\\ rejei\xe7\xe3o\\ no\\ cancelamento\\ da\\ desagrega\xe7\xe3o'
```